# How to make nntplib author name human readable?

Tags: character-encoding, python-2.5

python NNTPLib is giving me author name such as ,

"=?Utf-8?B?RGVubmlzIEJhc2hhbQ==?= < someone@someforum.com >"

(Quotes for clarity).

How do i encode this text in human readable format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double equals at the end was a dead giveaway.  Base 64 uses that for padding strings that do not have an even multiple of 4 bytes.

**In python:**

```
print "RGVubmlzIEJhc2hhbQ==".decode('base_64')
```

**In PHP:**

```
<?php echo base64_decode("RGVubmlzIEJhc2hhbQ=="); ?>
```

Enjoy.

PS...  Dennis Basham